# detect when UIPopoverController has finished presented UIImageViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have the UIImagePickerController as a content View Controller for the UIPopoverController.  I need to detect when the popover has just finished presented (has just showed up).  UIPopoverController does not have any delegate for this.  I can't seem to find a way to detect the UIImagePickerController as well.  (This is for iPad)

Any suggestions?

```
// UIImagePickerController let's the user choose an image.
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
self.popover.delegate = self;
[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.openPhotosButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: You're looking for something like viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear? (methods you override when implementing a UIViewController).

Comment: Yes, but the content view controller of the popover in this case is the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: I see... you can't override UIImagePickerController, so the viewDidLoad approach won't work.  What are you trying to achieve?  There may be another way to do it.

Comment: I need to hide the status bar from showing up when UIImagePickerController is presented.  (iOS 7 related)

Comment: Ok, understood.  The ImagePickerDelegate is also a UINavigationControllerDelegate, and so it includes -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated - which is called at the right time.  Just make your class implement UINavigationControllerDelegate too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UIImagePickerDelegate is also a UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Your class should implement UINavigationControllerDelegate and include the following:

```
 -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
     // [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];  // This one works for me: OP
    }
```

I've tested this and it hides the navigation bar.  I am not sure if doing so conflicts with the HIG though.

Comment: This delegate works perfectly.  It gets called when the ImagePickerView is presented and when taping on any albums.  So it is a right place to hide the status bar.  Thanks.

Comment: Tried a few other solutions but all don't work quite well. This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Thise should help:

- UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
- UIPopoverControllerDelegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover

You have delegates for both

Comment: Oh - how you are showing it - can you update question with code of how you show it ? You do some animation or smth ?