# UIImagePickerController detect when album is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios7

I need to detect when an album is selected (any album).  The `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` only get called when an image or movie is selected.

Any suggestions?

[image]

I need to prevent the status bar from showing up caused by the UIImagePickerController when you tap on any albums. (iOS 7 related)

Comment: No, you cannot observe that. There is no API for that. Actually, what you gonna do with that? Why do you wanna detect that?

Comment: I need to prevent the status bar from showing up caused by the UIImagePickerController when you tap on any albums.  (iOS 7 related)

Comment: Why not hide the status bar before you present the UIImagePickerController and show before it dismisses? I hope that would work. I will check out for iOS 7 and get back to you.

Comment: That would be a normal course.  Unfortunately, this thing didn't work that way with iOS7.  The status bar keeps showing up after the picker is presented, and again after any album is selected. Until big A fixes this, a search for a solution is still in progress...

Comment: I got a perfect place to hide the status bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831764/detect-when-uipopovercontroller-has-finished-presented-uiimageviewcontroller