# Status bar appears again after showing MPMediaPickerController modal

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, statusbar, mpmediapickercontroller

I hid status bar in my app by setting `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` and by this code:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

By when I show the MPMediaPickerController modal with `[self presentViewController:mpMediaPlayerController animated:YES completion:^{}]`;, the status bar is being show again.

How can I hide it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833115/uiimagepickercontroller-detect-when-album-is-selected

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the MPMediaPickerController and add:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting back from MPMediaPlayerController again hide status bar in ViewWillAppear method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Hope it will work.