# How to stop status bar appearing after waking in Guided Access on iOS7?

Tags: ios, ipad, guided-access

We've had an issue reported where the status bar sometimes appears overlaid on our app after sleeping and waking the iPad. Our setup is as follows:

- Our app is landscape only (left and right)
- I've enabled guided access on the device
- I've enabled the sleep/wake button in guided access
- We recently updated our app and iPads to iOS7, and did not see this issue in iOS6

After investigating I've found the following when in guided access:

- With the device in landscape, repeatedly sleeping and waking (using the power button on the device) occasionally (~1 in 10) causes the status bar to appear in landscape orientation and then immediately fade
- Sleeping the device, then rotating to portrait, then waking, very consistently (~8 in 10) causes the status bar to appear in portrait orientation and stay on screen

I tried using the following, called from applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

But this had no effect. I then tried calling this after a short delay, and then continually on a loop (both had no effect). Finally I tried to show the status bar and then hide, and was surprised to see 2 status bars - one being the one I can control programatically using the above code snippet, and another one being caused by waking in guided access.

Does anyone know a fix or work around for this? I've got no idea how I'd gain control over the 2nd status bar? (This sounds like a bug in iOS7 to me?).

Unfortunately guided access and sleeping devices are key to our company's workflow, and the status bar on the side has been reported to be causing issues with pressing buttons (plus of course it looks unprofessional!). The only work around we've found is to sleep and wake the device again, which usually fixes the issue, but isn't great.

Comment: This solution might apply to your setup as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831764/detect-when-uipopovercontroller-has-finished-presented-uiimageviewcontroller

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in iOS 8. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope we never found a solution to this unfortunately. I raised a bug report with Apple (with a detailed explanation of the issue, screenshots etc) but never heard back :(

Comment: We also reported the bug to Apple. Today it was confirmed as a Duplicate of 15726062. Unfortunately there is no [OpenRadar](http://openradar.me) report for the original bug, so that is probably all we'll hear about it until it's fixed.

Comment: If the problem doesn't appear if your app would support both landscape and portrait, then just support both orientations. Besides for games I find it absolutely unacceptable not to support all orientations on iPad, as a user I would refuse to use such an app. Hopefully with size classes and split screen multitasking Apple will bann such apps from the store.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[application setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

in your apps plist file add a row call it **"View controller-based status bar appearance"** and set it to **NO**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we already have the plist entry, and the setStatusBarHidden call doesn't help unfortunately (I guess as you might expect from the investigation presented above)